# How to make UITextField move up when keyboard is present?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I prevent a `UITextField` from being hidden by the keyboard?

Comment: please give more detail on what you have tried already

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume this is happening on a `UIViewController`. If so, you can setup the following two functions to be called when the keyboard will show/hide, and respond appropriately in their blocks.

Setting up the `UIViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate... {

    var frameView: UIView!
```

First, in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.frameView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))

    // Keyboard stuff.
    let center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}
```

Then implement the following two functions to respond to your `NotificationCenter` functions defined in `viewDidLoad()` above. I give you an example of moving the entire view, but you can also animate just the `UITextField`s.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = keyboardSize.height

    let _: CGFloat = info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber as! CGFloat


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.frameView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.frameView.frame.origin.y - keyboardHeight), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    }, completion: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = keyboardSize.height

    let _: CGFloat = info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber as! CGFloat

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.frameView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.frameView.frame.origin.y + keyboardHeight), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Don't forget to remove the notifications when leaving your view

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: What's the variable frameview?

Comment: Sorry, left that code out. frameview was simply a UIView that was the entire width and height of the UIViewController. Updated in my answer. But keep in mind you don't have to move the entire view up, you could just move the positions of the uitextview.

Comment: And how i move the position of the uitextview?

Comment: For example: You could position your UITextView in a UIView, say called textViewWrapperView - which would be positioned in your viewDidLoad function. Then in keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide instead of altering the position of self.frameView.frame you would alter the position of self.textViewWrapperView.frame. Make sense?

Comment: @Alex, I've updated this to satisfy the Swift 2.0 compiler. I wanted to notify you because I am changing your answer slightly and this will give you the opportunity to change my edit.

Comment: This does not work for me, the view temporarily moves down and leaves a big black space above it then slides back to its original position.

Comment: I prefer Dan's solution. Also when you have multiple UITextFields this will slide the View up multiple times. I prevented this with a "keyboardShowing" boolean.

Comment: For anyone using a `storyboard` and trying to make it work but can't, just make sure that `self.view` has **leading**, **top** and **trailing** `constraints`. Otherwise, it probably won't work.

Comment: Note for iOS13 iPad apps the UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey should be tested, if it is not 1 then the keyboard notification is being generated for another app. Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardislocaluserinfokey?language=objc

Answer (score 9):

Here is the simple solution in Swift. I translated some Objective-C code that worked for me in the past.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) { // became first responder

    //move textfields up
    let myScreenRect: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let keyboardHeight : CGFloat = 216

    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    var movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.35
    var needToMove: CGFloat = 0

    var frame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    if (textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height + /*self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + */UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height > (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight)) {
    needToMove = (textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height + /*self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height +*/ UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height) - (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight);
    }

    frame.origin.y = -needToMove
    self.view.frame = frame
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        //move textfields back down
        UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
        var movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.35
        var frame : CGRect = self.view.frame
        frame.origin.y = 0
        self.view.frame = frame
        UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: Thnx,,,, super solution.

Comment: swift says, movementDuration was never used. is there a reason to include this?

Comment: i forgot to remove that line. you can just comment it out

Comment: Hi, when I change of screen and go back to this one, the function is called but my view does not move up .. I'm using a tab bar controller so the view is only loaded once. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Hard-coding the keyboard height of 216 is potentially incorrect. See above solution for how to get the actual height.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4** code, It is very simple instead of using many things like NSNotificationCenter, then calculating the height of everything and making conditions makes this more complicated,

The Simple way to do this is coded below, it will work to move up the view.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        moveTextField(textfield: textField, moveDistance: -250, up: true)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        moveTextField(textfield: textField, moveDistance: -250, up: false)
}

func moveTextField(textfield: UITextField, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool) {
    let moveDuration = 0.3
    let movement: CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance: -moveDistance)
    UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

you can change that -250 value according to the placement of your textfields.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using a `UIScrollView` or any of its subclasses, e.g., `UITableView`, you can also manipulate the `contentInset` property. That way you do not have to mess with `frame`, `bounds`, `NSLayoutConstraint` or `NSLayoutAnchor`.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = keyboardSize.height
    let duration = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.tableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let duration = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! TimeInterval
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.tableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0

```
 var activeField: UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ProfileViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ProfileViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
        activeField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
        activeField = nil
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if (self.activeField?.frame.origin.y)! >= keyboardSize.height {
                self.view.frame.origin.y = keyboardSize.height - (self.activeField?.frame.origin.y)!
            } else {
                self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42220193/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 use this code

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

                let center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RFLogInViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RFLogInViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        }



 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = keyboardSize.height

        let _: CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber as! CGFloat


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.view.frame.origin.y - keyboardHeight), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)

    }




 func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = keyboardSize.height

        let _: CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber as! CGFloat

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

              self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.view.frame.origin.y + keyboardHeight), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)

    }


  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'IQKeyboardManager' library into your project, and Done. You have not to do anything else. For reference please check this url.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**
I have seen numerous of answer and plenty of them did not work for me where I have a UIViewController With numerous of text fields.

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) I have translate the example to Swift 4

Your content needs to be embedded within an scrollview.

**Add the notification listeners for when the keyboard will appear or dissappear.**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

**Implement UITextField Delegates**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    currentTextField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {

    currentTextField = nil

}
```

**Selectors**

```
@objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("\(logClassName): keyboardWDidShow")

    let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    let keyboardSize:CGSize = keyboardFrame!.size

    let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    trackScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    trackScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var aRect:CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height

    if !(aRect.contains(currentTextField!.frame.origin)){

        trackScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(currentTextField!.frame, animated: true)

    }

}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){

    print("\(logClassName): keyboardWillHide")

    let contentInsents:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    trackScrollView.contentInset = contentInsents
    trackScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsents

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should have scrollview 
step 1:find the height of key board

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo ? [UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as ? NSValue) ? .cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        a = keyboardHeight
    }
}
```

step 2: bind the delegete methods of textfield

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    utility.setUserDefaultBool(value: false, key: "FrameMoveFlag") //flag
    let b = view1.frame.height - textField.frame.origin.y
    if (b < 350) {
        view1.frame.origin.y = view1.frame.origin.y + (view1.frame.height - textField.frame.origin.y) - (a + 50)
        utility.setUserDefaultBool(value: true, key: "FrameMoveFlag") //flag
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if (utility.getUserDefaultBOOLForKey(key: "FrameMoveFlag") == true) {
        view1.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** code for [Geiger answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28289044/7030209)

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { // became first responder

    //move textfields up
    let myScreenRect: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let keyboardHeight : CGFloat = 216

    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    var movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.35
    var needToMove: CGFloat = 0

    var frame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    if (textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height > (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight - 30)) {
        needToMove = (textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height) - (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight - 30);
    }

    frame.origin.y = -needToMove
    self.view.frame = frame
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //move textfields back down
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    var movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.35
    var frame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    frame.origin.y = 0
    self.view.frame = frame
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually work with appearing and disappearing of the keyboard, just use the UITableViewController and it will handle all text fields in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my gist, I use a scrollView for my case, but it works for any kind of view, you only have to remove the scrollView part and replace it with your view.
The gist is very well commented so you will also understand how this case is handled.
https://gist.github.com/Sjahriyar/916e93153a29dc602b45f29d39182352

Answer (score 0):

I created `KeyboardController` to handle the keyboard issue. All that needs to be done is call `setUpKeyBoardListeners()` and set the `lastElement` as whatever the last element in your view is.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/espitia/ef830cf677fa1bc33ffdf16ac12d0204