# Swift Tableview textfield not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextfield, tableview

I know, Inside the tableview (UITableview Controller) if we use the text field it is automatically scrolling when the keypad display. Objective-c also working fine. But Swift it is not scrolling. When I select the textfield keypad is overlap the textfield. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Sometimes if you just start typing the OS will automatically scroll for you. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. I tried. I tried iPhone and iPad. Not  working @Arc676

Comment: Yes. I am using TableviewController with static cell. When I try the Objective-c it is working. @EICaptain

Comment: this answers your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift