# Tableview is not remaining same when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I researched all over stackoverflow. I found too many solutions but they did not work properly. This is a typical ios question.

I have to move tableview when the keyboard appears. I tried following code:

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

        let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardFrame.size.height, 0)
        self.tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets
}
```

**State 1: There is no keyboard and everything looks fine:**

[image]

**State 2: The keyboard appeared, and tableview is not showing the last row. You can compare with state 1.**

[image]

How can I do this thing properly? If user scrolled to top then when touches the textfield, **tableview should show same position, no last row.** I mean I don't want any scroll to bottom code when keyboard appears. Tableview should remain same with/without keypoard appear status. You can check the Whatsapp I need exact same mechanism. How can I do this?

PS: Don't mind the textfield, I removed their move to above of keyboard code in order to test tableview.

Comment: are you saying that you want the view to move with the keyboard?

Comment: if so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift/32915049#32915049