# how to offset text view equals height of the keyboard in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a text view in my project and I want when user tap the text field it moves up equals to the height of the keyboard I used this code for getting height of the keyboard and It gives me the size of the keyboard

```
static var sizeForOffsetKeyboard = CGFloat()

    var heightKeyboard : CGFloat?
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardShown(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}

func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let infoKey  = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey],
        let rawFrame = (infoKey as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
        let keyboardFrame = view.convert(rawFrame, from: nil)
        self.heightKeyboard = keyboardFrame.size.height

        levelChatViewController.sizeForOffsetKeyboard = heightKeyboard!

        print(levelChatViewController.sizeForOffsetKeyboard)
        // Now is stored in your heightKeyboard variable
    }
}
```

But I didn't get the result and the textview won't move up with the height of the keyboard

so here is the codes for offset textview

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {


   animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: levelChatViewController.sizeForOffsetKeyboard)
}
```

Comment: You can use UITableViewController for automatic scrolling. Check my ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233089/move-textfield-up-when-keyboard-displays/45233564#45233564

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift and its ok But when textfield is editing and user change the keyboard the textfield won't move with new keyboard

Comment: You have to keep on adding height when keyboard based on which textfiled is currently selected. You can use UITableViewController and you can achieve what you desire with zero code.

Comment: You can check ans by Celil  and Fedya and Rohit in link you shared. Those ans can be helpful in your case.

Comment: I didn't used UITableViewController and because of lots of codes I can't change it can you give me another way ?

Comment: Have you checked ans by Celil and Fedya and Rohit in link you shared above??

Comment: I know you would have to change it no issues. You can keep UITableViewController for future when in need.

Comment: Sorry I have make a big mistake my texts are in textview not textfield I will Edit question

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Add pod

```
      pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

In your AppDelegate

```
     import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
```

inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

     }
```

This will manage all the text filed of your project and you do not have to write anything anywhere else

Just try it once you will love it

To know more https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: I don't want to use pod files because my project size is very huge

Comment: 745 KB  in size only

Comment: I have read that thanks for helping but I need some thing simple so I decided to get the sizes manual thanks for helping