# Keyboard height 0

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to move a stackview above the keyboard when user is typing.I am using the following code to get the height of the keyboard (taken from [Move view with keyboard using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift)).

The first time the keyboard appears, the code works,`keyboardSize.height` prints out to be `226.0`. However, when the keyboard reappears after the first time, `keyboardSize.height` prints out to be `0.0`. As a result, I am having trouble consistently moving my stackview up when the keyboard appears. Occasionally, the code would work again after the first try, but it does not last more than one time, and behaves inconsistently.

When I simply print out `keyboardSize`, the first time I would get `(0.0, 736.0, 414.0, 226.0)`. After the first time, `keyboardSize` prints out to be `(0.0, 736.0, 414.0, 0.0)`, so only the height becomes incorrect.

How could I get the height of the keyboard consistently? Why is this issue occurring?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue{
        print(keyboardSize.height)
        ...
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue{ ... }
}
```

Comment: could you please describe what "when the keyboard reappears after the first time" means?

Comment: @TungFam   Yes. When I type something into the search bar, the keyboard appears. When i'm done typing and press search, the keyboard disappears. When I reedit text in the search bar, the keyboard would appear again, that is what I meant by "when the keyboard reappears after the first time".

Comment: Have found a solution for this one yet? I think it's an issue with iOS 11 beta. Because I was facing the same thing and when I tested it on iOS 10 it didn't happen.

Comment: @AJZ. Did you ever figure this issue out? I'm currently dealing with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this;

> UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey

Objective C;

```
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing the stack view above keyboard using input accessory view and you have canBecomeFirstResponder of accessory view to true than when the keyboard appears firt time then it'll give you original height but when you close the keyboard tgen incase of accessoryview usage first it goes to keyboard close notification and the again to keyboard open notification function.  So you'll be getting keyboard open height on closing also.  Use breakpoints in both functions to confirm it and solve your problem by using some check variables.  Note******  must read about input accesory view best way to add view above keyboard like in chat apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this **code**:

```
CGSize keyboardSize = 
  [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```