# UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification swift implementation

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

For a long while now, I've been looking for a Swift implementation that utilizes `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` so far I haven't come across anything. I'm trying to get this working so that I can handle the keyboard show and hide in one method as stated in the documentation [here](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_keyboard_covers_text_field) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) written in objective-c.

and replace these:

```
// Register your Notification, To know When Keyboard appears.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myKeyboardWillShowMethod), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

// Register your Notification, To know When Keyboard hides.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myKeyboardWillHideMethod), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Comment: If you know how to write the code for those two notifications, what problem are you having with the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification notification?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to get the height of the keyboard when it appears and adjust my view, then reset my view when it disappears. This is the idea I was going for..

Comment: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardMovements(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)`

Comment: `@objc func handleKeyboardMovements(notification: Notification) { 
       // need to get height of keyboard when it opens
      // scroll my view up and down as keyboard shows and hides
 }`

Comment: @user8244799 Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift

Comment: @user8244799 Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and update with all relevant information.