# screen is black when move view in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have general message view controller I am sending message using textfield but keyboard is covered the text fields. I can refer
[Move view with keyboard using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift#)
 this link added some code but after that some portion shows black. how to avoid the screen black after sending the message

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is code

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GenralMessageViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GenralMessageViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }


   @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
           }
        }
    }

   @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
          if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
              self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
           }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Try changing `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just wrong. You have no business changing the `frame` of `self.view`. The main view of a view controller must be left in place where it is. Wrap your interface in a subview of the main view and move the subview (if you insist on using this approach to avoiding being covered by the keyboard).

Comment: I second this answer. use a constraint, a scroll view, a sub view, a container... out of all the ways you can do it, moving your main view isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your end y origin back to 0 instead of a calculated value.

```
   @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
          if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
              self.view.frame.origin.y == 0
           }
        }
   }
```